# How to parse HTTP GET method object in JS

Tags: javascript, get

I have variable "parse" in which is saved GET like this:

```
<div class="List_modal" data-target-input-id="Product" data-target-input-hidden="Product_Hidden">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Base</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
          <a title="Wsome talking " href="#" class="List_Item">
                               123.123.123.123
                                <input type="hidden" class="Code" value="123.123.123.123" />
                                <input type="hidden" class="Base" value="I NEED THIS TEXT" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a title="ere random text too" href="#" class="List_Item">
                                randomtextrandomtext
                                <input type="hidden" class="Code" value="123.123.123.123" />
                                <input type="hidden" class="Base" value="I NEEED THIS TEXT" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i need is to get only string from input class "Base" and "Code". I tried RegEx but i am not JS developer and i cant make Functions and using jQuery becasue this script is used in Data Integration Framework. Have any idea how to get this to values? And it should be universal because every time i scrap some site i have different values i code and base class.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is web scraping, it's a whole art form in itself. There are commercial places like scraperwiki who will do it for you, or look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

As you have the html in a file (presumably) you don't have to use javascript, you can use a toolset that you are more familiar with

Comment: Ofcourse i can but it have to be done in JS. I am trying to parse it in regex101 site i dont understand so much RegEx yet.

Comment: The general advice given is 'dont try to parse html', because HTML is often malformed, and your parsing will not work with it. The browser is  the best html parser around, or failiing that you can use something like phantomjs

Comment: That all is String object so i can parse it. I need only 2 values from this short file, any idea how to do it by regex?

Comment: Is this the real HTML? The input fields don't even have id's on them, which suggests that some view framework will modify it before it is rendered. How do you get the data - as a string variable, or do you have to read it from file? Are you limited to inline javascript only?

Comment: It is "GetProducts?" GET request on some site which i cant add here, and this "html" is saved to variable as string.

Comment: Just imagine that is simple String object, how to parse it with regex to get result two values after Code and Base class.